# Betting with VPN

Tags: terms-of-service, gambling, netherlands

The Stake Online Casino is not available in the Netherlands. However, you can bypass this geoblocking with a VPN. Is this a legal thing to do? And can Stake find out in any way?

Comment: They might find out after you make a big win. And might have no obligation to pay. Anyway, how are you paying? That is quite likely traceable.

Comment: I think the final question is off topic here and should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stake is obviously logging all traffic sources - that's how they geofence site access to begin with - and will know and can investigate traffic from the IPs of known VPN services. They will probably also check all funding sources and payouts to see if they match the geographic locations of accounts.

You must agree to the TOS to open an account, and because using a VPN is against the TOS, you have violated it and they reserve the right to close your account (Read the US version: https://stake.us/policies/terms ):

> 23. DEACTIVATION/SUSPENSION OF ACCOUNT
>
> 23.1. Without limiting clause 4, we reserve the right, at our sole discretion, to deactivate or suspend your Customer Account
> (notwithstanding any other provision contained in these Terms and
> Conditions) where we have reason to believe that you have engaged or
> are likely to engage in any of the following activities:
>
> i) you attempt to use your Customer Account through a VPN, proxy or
> similar service that masks or manipulates the identification of your
> real location, or by otherwise providing false or misleading
> information regarding your citizenship, location or place of
> residence, or by playing Games using the Platform through a third
> party or on behalf of a third party;
>
> ...
>
> k) you are located in a jurisdiction where participation is illegal;